# How can I efficiently make several hundred signs for a plant sale?

Tags: print-design, automation, microsoft-office

This is my first StackExchange question ever, yay!

First I will describe how I made the signs last year:

I started with a spreadsheet of plant names and prices, as well as a folder of images (one for each plant). I created a PowerPoint slide *(with dimensions that would allow two signs to fit on one standard sheet of paper, with a gap for laminating and cutting... I put boxes on the slide for the two text items)* and then duplicated it for each sign. **I spent many hours copy/pasting each plant name, price, and image into each slide, and re-sizing the images to fit.** Finally, I exported it to a PDF and printed two-to-a-sheet.

My question is: **How can I do this more efficiently?** If I should use anything besides Microsoft Office, I would prefer software that is free (as in beer).

EDIT: I just found out that I have access to MS Publisher, and it looks like that will be much easier than trying to force MS Word to work with pictures.

Comment: Where did you Copy and Paste the Plant Information from? Is it on a website? A spreadsheet? A database?

Comment: @Ryan spreadsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a technique called **Data Merging**. In Microsoft Office products there are two options:

- [Mail Merge](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx)
- [Catalog Merge](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/publisher-help/create-catalogs-or-directories-RZ001078363.aspx?section=3)

Then you'll want to pay special attention, and [learn how to Merging Pictures](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/publisher-help/merge-pictures-into-a-publication-HP001038506.aspx).

Essentially, you'll be using your spreadsheet but might need to create a new one (to not ruin your original) and get the formatting right. Typically avoid spaces in column headings, and for the images follow the instructions--- do not place your images into the document, place the location of the image into the document. Then you'll use **Microsoft Word's Mail Merge** to do most of the work for you by importing the data from the spreadsheet.

If you get stuck you can probably find more help on the topic at http://www.superuser.com

Comment: I just found out that I have access to MS Publisher, and it looks like that will be much easier than trying to force MS Word to work with pictures.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, you could lay that out in MS Word and use a mail merge. One page, one database, one mail merge later, you're done.